Row count and data in same query using EF core
I have a web page that paginates data returned from the database usually using some filter. I return the data on the selected page plus the total number of results so pagination can be configured. I achieve this now by running two queries. One to get the total result count and the other to get the data for a requested page. I wonder if would be more efficient and faster to do this in a single query. I can achieve this by running this type of query in MySQL:
SELECT 
    u.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM
    Users u
WHERE
    u.Name Like '%John%'
ORDER BY
    u.Name
LIMIT 0,30

I attempted translating this query to LINQ with EF Core like this:
var filterQuery = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Contains("John");
var data = filterQuery
    .Select(x => new {
        Count = queryable.Count(),
        Data = x
    })
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(30)
    .ToList();

But EF core still executes 2 queries:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Name Like '%John%'

stores that in a variable which is then used in a subsequent query as a field.
SELECT
    @__Count_1 AS `Count`,
    u.*
FROM
    Users AS u
WHERE
    u.Name Like '%John%'
ORDER BY
    u.Name
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

I tried some SQL to LINQ translators which do not seem to help.

Your user entity has a Count property for this to represent data that connected with distinct query and not a User here? Sounds to me the optimization is something not well fitting in the EF world. If you want optimization on SQL level this way stay away from ORMS like EF and take something that's more close to SQL that you then can optimize when you now how and only use something for model mapping.

User entity does not have a count property. Imagine a simple Users table with Id and Name columns.

Your only possible option to make this work is to use GroupBy(x => 1) and then re-select back out of the grouping https://dotnetfiddle.net/itWnGn but OVER is still not generated.

I think this will be supported in version 9 of EF Core see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12747

EF do not support window functions in LINQ query.


EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL. It's meant to load a graph of connected objects and persist changes to them, NOT act as a SQL replacement.  2) it seems the real question is how to use paging.  Using COUNT(*) OVER () on every page is not a great idea as you pay for the count calculation on every page. You only need to calculate the count once and reuse it. 3) The count(*) query will probably result in a simpler and faster execution plan.


Dunno, I ran that scenario through SQL Server and looked at the execution plan. With a relatively small table the execution time was the same, but fetching a count then data separately was two very simple execution plans vs. one significantly larger one with nested loops and table spools. Then there is the question of extracting the row count which appears as a column in every one of the fetched 30 rows. Counts are something that doesn't need to be refreshed every page, just periodically. It does work though and return the count ignoring the limit but including the filter.
